# What tools are available for DTS to SSIS package conversion

Tags: ssis, dts

What are the tools available for DTS to SSIS package conversion as a part of the SQL Server upgrade and which ones do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting the packages isn't an option for larger scale companies where they have thousands of packages. I was dealing with a customer the other day that received a quote for more than $500k to convert their packages and 2 years and a staff of 8. No one can wait that long to proceed with their migration project. The DTS xChange tool by Pragmatic Works will automate 90% of the migration for you. The tool has migrated more than 200K packages at this point and comes with an additional tool to help with ActiveX Script Tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large amount of packages, you might try the migration wizard from microsoft.  It will not migrate everything.
It will give you a nice start.
Of course you will test the converted packages thoroughly.

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966519.aspx

```
Integration Services

Upgrade Tool: None
Migration Tool: DTS Migration Wizard
Migration Method: Migration Wizard converts 50-70 percent of tasks, requires some manual migration; runtime DTS DLLs available in SSIS; package re-architecture is recommended
```

Some screen shots of the process.

http://wiki.sqlis.com/default.aspx/SQLISWiki/MigrationWizardSteps.html

Comment: thanks
yes there are large amount of packages
Are there any other tools than migration wizard

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is so much better than DTS (especially the 2008 version) that you might do better to rewrite the packages.

Comment: That is what he is asking for.  Something to aid in the rewriting.

Comment: No, he's asking for a conversion. I mean redesign to take advantage of new features. DTS didn't have data flow did it? Or real loops?

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't trust any such tool, if any exist. These conversion tool are typically only any use as a learning aid.

Rewrite the packages in SSIS as and when you get a chance.

EDIT: Downvotes!!?!?? Jeez!  So are you guys all out there running apps which have been converted from VB to .net against databases converted using the oracle to sql conversion tool?  I'll bet you're not.

Comment: Saying you wouldn't trust a utility and not even knowing about existing tools seems overly pessimistic.  Of course, none of us would expect DTS go 'poof' into SSIS, but you should give the technology a chance!

Comment: @Sam - I know enough about DTS and SSIS and the differences between them to know that no tool is going to give a decent conversion.  At the core of SSIS is the data pipeline, whereas DTS just runs a series of tasks. You say yourself no tool is going to do it, but then criticise me for saying the same.